# XPage is blank in Webbrowser

Tags: xpages

After a new Domino Designer Installation (newest Trail) I created a simple, simple Xpage and try to open it in a Browser (FF). The Xpage was loaded but has not HTML code. In other words its a blank page.

What did I do wrong ?

Update :

This is the XPage source code , very simple

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" rendered="true"> 
        Hello World 
        <xp:br></xp:br> 
        <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1" style="width:82.0px"> 
                <xp:selectItem itemLabel="Eis"></xp:selectItem> 
        </xp:comboBox> 
</xp:view>
```

UPDATE :

The solution to my question was answered by stwissel givving a hint to the viewport. Indeed the viewport 80 was blocked by another program. Can' remember which one.  Then I changed the viewport under preferences->Domino Designer -> Web View Port to 8080 and it works. But I doubt that this is a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check if "Build automatically" is turned off. If so (recommended setting btw) just build the project manually after every change you made.
Also check if the page has the "rendered" property set to "false". This will result in an empty response though you won't get an error message.

Comment: Automatically build is turned ON. It has no effect. Where do I find the "rendered property" ?

Comment: Open the source, goto the xp:view level and check "All Properties". There you'll find "rendered"

Comment: Ok, in "All Properties" the "renedered" property has no entry - it's blank. I set it manually to "true" but it has no effect. The Browser XPage is still blank.

Comment: Paste your source from the xpage here and the html rendered. Any errors in the problem view or log?

Comment: @stwissel -  concering source code see UPDATE above. There is no "rendered HTML" if you refer to the browser. What do you mean with "in the problem view" and where do I find "log" ?

Comment: @stwissel - I found "Log and Trace Viewer" if you mean this tool. There are quite some warnings. What do you especially look for ?

Comment: Anything that looks like a code error. Be aware: the log for local browser preview is in [data-directory]/domino/workspace/logs not [data-directory]/workspace/log (that's for the client itself). Which opens the next interesting questions: a) is it a local database or on a server b) can you preview it in the client c) did you keep the data directory below the program (BAD idea) or point to your user profile directory (like the shared install of a plain client) d) any other http task running?

Comment: @stwissel - There is a "View log" item in the Help/Support menu. There I see warnings as stated above. When I look via the file explorer in `data/domino/workspace/logs`there are no logs at all. This is maybe because Notes and Designer where installed just previously.

Comment: @stwissel - your questions : a) it's a local .nsf file. b) yes I can preview it in notes. c) If you refer to the path where Domino Designer stores and access its rescources than this is `Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\Data\...`   Your question concerning `user profile directory` I do not understand.

Comment: Windows limits access to program files. Having data there is a bad idea. You save yourself a lot of trouble wiping the install and reinstall it and select a manual directory for data - not the default, but instead  c:\users\yourname\LocalData\IBM\Notes\Data - where a normal client install would put data - IMHO a bug in the designer installer to propose program files.

Comment: And u are sure nothing else is on port 80? A good candidate spoiling the fun is your anti-virus program blocking it with its own tasks

Comment: @stwissel -  using another path is a good point. But this brings to the question : How does DD renders its HTML code for previewing ? Into Memory ? If not where does DD renders it to ? To the same path where the .nsf files are ?

Comment: In memory. But there are temp files. My bet is on port 80

Comment: There is an anit-virus app running. Temporarily I disabled it , also I disabled web protection with port 80, 8080 , 3228. Preview in Browser still does not work. Preview in Notes does work

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question myself, because there are different behaviours with FireFox and Edge Browser. In another try with Edge the browser shows a 404 Eror, while FireFox did not do that. So the question finally has to be why is there a 404 Error coming up

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning the project? Project >>> Clean (from the top toolbar in designer)

Comment: The only other think I could suggest is making sure that the database is signed with an ID of appropriate privileges?

I copy/pasted your code into a blank xpage, built and it previewed as expected for me....